# ¿Cómo cuento cada vocal y el total de ellas de un String con hilos?

Tags: java, hilos

Me dan una frase y he de contar cuántas *a e i o u* hay y además el total. El total si lo hago pero cuantas *a e i o u* no caigo.

```
public class Hilo extends Thread {

    private static String frase;
    private char vocal;
    private static int numHilos = 0;

    public Hilo1(String frase, char vocal) {
        this.frase = frase;
        this.vocal = vocal;
    }

    public static void setFrase(String frase) {
        Hilo1.frase = frase;
    }

    public static String getFrase() {
        return frase;
    }

    @Override
  public void run() {
    int a = Contador.getA();
    int e = Contador.getE();
    int i = Contador.getI();
    int o = Contador.getO();
    int u = Contador.getU();
    int sum = Contador.getSuma();
    for (int x = 0; x < frase.length(); x++) {
        if (frase.charAt(x) == vocal && vocal == 'a') {
            a++;
            sum++;
        } else if (frase.charAt(x) == vocal && vocal == 'e') {
            e++;
            sum++;
        } else if (frase.charAt(x) == vocal && vocal == 'i') {
            i++;
            sum++;
        } else if (frase.charAt(x) == vocal && vocal == 'o') {
            o++;
            sum++;
        } else if (frase.charAt(x) == vocal && vocal == 'u') {
            u++;
            sum++;
        }
    }
    Contador.setSuma(sum);
    Contador.setA(a);
    Contador.setE(e);
    Contador.setI(i);
    Contador.setO(o);
    Contador.setU(u);
    numHilos++;
        }
```

}

A continuación la clase Contador:

```
public class Contador {

private static int a;
private static int e;
private static int i;
private static int o;
private static int u;
private static int suma;

public static int getA() {
    return a;
}

public static void setA(int a) {
    Contador.a = a;
}

public static int getE() {
    return e;
}

public static void setE(int e) {
    Contador.e = e;
}

public static int getI() {
    return i;
}

public static void setI(int i) {
    Contador.i = i;
}

public static int getO() {
    return o;
}

public static void setO(int o) {
    Contador.o = o;
}

public static int getU() {
    return u;
}

public static void setU(int u) {
    Contador.u = u;
}

public static int getSuma() {
    return suma;
}

public static void setSuma(int suma) {
    Contador.suma = suma;
}
```

Esto es el main

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce la frase: ");
        Hilo1.setFrase(entrada.nextLine());
        String frase = Hilo1.getFrase();
        Hilo1 a = new Hilo1(frase, 'a');
        Hilo1 e = new Hilo1(frase, 'e');
        Hilo1 i = new Hilo1(frase, 'i');
        Hilo1 o = new Hilo1(frase, 'o');
        Hilo1 u = new Hilo1(frase, 'u');
        a.start();
        e.start();
        i.start();
        o.start();
        u.start();
        while (a.isAlive());
        while (e.isAlive());
        while (i.isAlive());
        while (o.isAlive());
        while (u.isAlive());
        if (Hilo1.getNumHilos() == 5) {
            System.out.println("las vocales totales son: " + Contador.getSuma() + "\n la frase tiene " + Contador.getA() + " aes"
                    + "\n la frase tiene " + Contador.getE() + " ees" + "\n la frase tiene " + Contador.getI() + " Ies"
                    + "\n la frase tiene " + Contador.getU() + " Ues");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Creo que tenes un concepto equivocado de lo que hace un hilo. Luego de tus preguntas anteriores y esta, me parece que no entendes el concepto. Antes de siquiera tratar de contestar esto (no se donde estan los hilos), me gustaria que le agregaras a tu pregunta, que entendes por hilo y que pensas que tiene que hacer cada hilo.

Comment: si no, pasate por el [chat] que creo que alli entre todos podremos ayudarte

Comment: @gbianchi he modificado la idea a ver como lo ves si no luego me paso por el chat que debo irme

Comment: Todos los hilos entran a esa clase y cada uno tinee una char asignado y comprueba si esta y lo cuenta no se como lo ves

Comment: Es algo asi como decis.. pero lo que esta codificado no tiene mucho sentido..

Comment: @gbianchi es todo lo que se me ocurre dentro de mis limitados conocimientos, debo de aprender por ciencia infusa ya que mi profesor no explica ni da ejemplos

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es muy confuso y tiene muchos problemas de lógica, te propongo esta solución.

**Clase Contador:**

```
public class Contador implements Runnable{
    private final String frase;
    private final char vocal;

    public Contador(String frase, char vocal){
        this.frase = frase;
        this.vocal = vocal;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int suma = 0;
        for(char letra : frase.toCharArray()){
            if((letra+"").equalsIgnoreCase(vocal+"")){
                suma++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("vocal: "+vocal+" suma: "+suma);
    }    
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce la frase: ");        
    String frase = entrada.nextLine();        

    Contador contadorA = new Contador(frase, 'a');
    Contador contadorE = new Contador(frase, 'e');
    Contador contadorI = new Contador(frase, 'i');
    Contador contadorO = new Contador(frase, 'o');
    Contador contadorU = new Contador(frase, 'u');

    Thread tA = new Thread(contadorA);
    Thread tE = new Thread(contadorE);
    Thread tI = new Thread(contadorI);
    Thread tO = new Thread(contadorO);
    Thread tU = new Thread(contadorU);

    tA.start();
    tE.start();
    tI.start();
    tO.start();
    tU.start();
}
```

Si quieres contar todas las vocales puedes crear otro hilo y modificar la clase Contador para que cuente todas.

Comment: gracias ya lo sulucione en el chat, las vocales totales lo hice con un contador statico en la misma clase thread